# Al deserializar un Json el valor de un dato numérico me lo convierte en cero

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

Consumiendo un Rest Api me trae estos datos en json

```
 {\"numero_ley\":66,\"caso\":\"a\",\"tasa_tope_tramo\":4,\"plazo\":15}
```

Cuando deserializo el Json con:

```
modelo variable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<modelo>(respuesta)
```

El valor para variable.

```
tasa_tope_tramo = 0
```

El campo tasa_tope_tramo me lo coloca en 0 y como se ve en respuesta es 4, el resto de los campos si están bien.

//Editado de comentario

```
public partial class LeyTTT 
{ public int Numero_Ley { get; set; } 
  public string caso { get; set; } 
  public double Taza_tope_tramo { get; set; } 
  public int Plazo { get; set; } 
}
```

Una ayudita por favor.  Saludos

Comment: Json devuelto del Api: "{\"numero_ley\":66,\"caso\":\"a\",\"tasa_tope_tramo\":4,\"plazo\":15}"

Comment: El Modelo es el siguiente:

Comment: public partial class LeyTTT
    {
        public int Numero_Ley { get; set; }
        public string caso { get; set; }
        public double Taza_tope_tramo { get; set; }
        public int Plazo { get; set; }
    }

Comment: tu propiedad es el problema, debes respetar mayusculas y minusculas y una la escribis con S, otra con z, lo cual estas hablando de propiedades diferentes para el Compilador.

Comment: tasa tope tramo es un entero pero lo esta deserealizando como un double. Quizas eso tambien le afecte

Answer (score 1):

Tu modelo tiene mal una propiedad. y debe ser igual al json que recibis. Sino deberias usar un `Attribute` para decorar la propiedad con `[JsonProperty()]`

```
public partial class LeyTTT 
{ public int Numero_Ley { get; set; } 
  public string caso { get; set; } 
  public double tasa_tope_tramo { get; set; } //Esta propiedad estaba mal definida
  public int Plazo { get; set; } 
}
```

En el caso de que no quieras cambiar la propiedad por algun motivo lo podes decorar asi:

```
public partial class LeyTTT 
{ public int Numero_Ley { get; set; } 
  public string caso { get; set; } 
  [JsonProperty("tasa_tope_tramo")]
  public double Taza_tope_tramo  { get; set; } //De esta manera no cambiar tu propiedad en la clase.
  public int Plazo { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para conocer como generar una clase en base al json ayudate con

https://app.quicktype.io/

entonces la clase seria

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class LeyTTT 
{
    [JsonProperty("numero_ley")]
    public long NumeroLey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("caso")]
    public string Caso { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tasa_tope_tramo")]
    public long TasaTopeTramo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("plazo")]
    public long Plazo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, siempre es bueno tener a quien preguntarle.  Saludos Totales

Comment: Si el error era que no se llamaban iguales, S y z. Tasa_tope_tramo y el otro Taza_tope_tramo.